# Manage windows service owned by System

Tags: windows, security

I have a windows service installed on my machine and when I view it from services.msc, the start, stop and other functionality are disabled for that service. I looked at the owner of the corresponding executable and found that it is owned by System. 

Now, if I try to change the owner, I get access denied error since the process is running and neither can I stop the process from task manager. How do I stop the service?


PS: I am an administrator on the machine.

Comment: The ownership of the executable has nothing to do with start/stop permissions. Those are controlled by the service descriptor on the service itself (viewed via the `sc sdshow` command line option, changable using `sc sdset`)

Comment: Note also that the stop, pause, and continue functions are only available if the service itself supports them.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to manage it through the application which created the service. Initially, I was not able to find the option to disable the said functionality from the UI of that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manage it through the application which created the service. Initially, I was not able to find the option to disable the said functionality from the UI of that application